# Graph API - valid POST not working using NODE JS

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, post

This issue has been consuming all my time, so I really need your help.

I will go straight to the point:

In order to create and add friends to an event I am using NODE JS request module. When I create an event I store the id to use it in another POST which, in turn, will add the friends to the event.

BOTH posts work in GRAPH API Explorer. The first to create the event and the second adding the friends to the event.

In MY APP I am able to create the event and get the ID but when I run the second POST it gives me the following answer:

```
{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

It doesn't make much sense because I am using exactly the same token and I have tested it in Graph Explorer hundred times!

POST syntax should be correct because I tested it many times in the GRAPH EXPLORER. Permissions should not be the issue, but as I said... I don't know what else can be the problem!

Please help me because I don't really know what else can I do!

**CODE**:

```
  var message = "&name=" + sender_name + " is inviting you for " + event_type + " via my app" + "&privacy_type=CLOSED&start_time=" + date_ics + "-0000";
  var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=' + access_token;


  console.log(url+message);

  var a = request({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    body: message
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
      obj = JSON.parse(body);
      event_id = obj.id;
      console.log(event_id);


        var message = "/invited?users=" + recipients_fb_id;
        var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + event_id;
        console.log(url+message);

        //PROBLEM STARTS HERE!
        request({
          url: url,
          method: 'POST',
          body: message
        }, function (err, res, body) {
          if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);

          }else{

            console.log("Erro: " + res.statusCode + body);
          }
        });

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second request you are not including the access token - this needs to be included in all requests.

Also, why not just put all the parameters into the url var instead of using the message?

```
var message = "";
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + event_id + "/invited?users=" + recipients_fb_id + "&access_token=" + access_token;
console.log(url);
```